# Is there some way of avoiding this implicit MPI_Allreduce() synchronisation?

Tags: mpi

I'm writing an MPI program that uses a library which makes its own MPI calls. In my program, I have a loop that calls a function from the library. The function that I'm calling from the library makes use of `MPI_Allreduce`.

The problem here is that in my program, some of the ranks can exit the loop before others and this causes the `MPI_Allreduce` call to just hang since not all ranks will be calling `MPI_Allreduce` again.

**Is there any way of programming around this without modifying the sources of the library I'm using?**

Below is the code for an example which demonstrates the execution pattern.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N_ITEMS 100000
#define ITERATIONS 32 

float *create_rand_nums(int num_elements) {
  float *rand_nums = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * num_elements);
  assert(rand_nums != NULL);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
    rand_nums[i] = (rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
  }
  return rand_nums;
}

void reduce_stddev(int world_rank, int world_size, int num_elements_per_proc)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "Calling %s: %d\n", __func__, world_rank);
  fflush(stdout);

  srand(time(NULL)*world_rank);
  float *rand_nums = NULL;
  rand_nums = create_rand_nums(num_elements_per_proc);

  float local_sum = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_elements_per_proc; i++) {
    local_sum += rand_nums[i];
  }

  float global_sum;
  fprintf(stdout, "%d: About to call all reduce\n", world_rank);
  fflush(stdout);
  MPI_Allreduce(&local_sum, &global_sum, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  fprintf(stdout, "%d: done calling all reduce\n", world_rank);
  fflush(stdout);
  float mean = global_sum / (num_elements_per_proc * world_size);

  float local_sq_diff = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < num_elements_per_proc; i++) {
    local_sq_diff += (rand_nums[i] - mean) * (rand_nums[i] - mean);
  }

  float global_sq_diff;
  MPI_Reduce(&local_sq_diff, &global_sq_diff, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, 0,
             MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (world_rank == 0) {
    float stddev = sqrt(global_sq_diff /
                        (num_elements_per_proc * world_size));
    printf("Mean - %f, Standard deviation = %f\n", mean, stddev);
  }

  free(rand_nums);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: avg num_elements_per_proc\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int num_elements_per_proc = atoi(argv[1]);

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  unsigned long long j = 0;

  for(j = 0; j < ITERATIONS; j++)
  {
    /* Function which calls MPI_Allreduce */
    reduce_stddev(world_rank, world_size, num_elements_per_proc);

    /* Simulates some processes leaving the loop early */
    if( (j == (ITERATIONS/2)) && (world_rank % 2 == 0))
    {
      fprintf(stdout, "%d exiting\n", world_rank);
      fflush(stdout);
      break;
    }
  }

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Finalize();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to pass a communicator into the library function, or is it exactly as shown in the example - i.e. hardcoded to call MPI_Allreduce on MPI_COMM_WORLD?

Comment: @timdykes no, I'm not able to pass a communicator into the function. The function is hardcoded unfortunately.

Comment: Instead of exiting the loop, simply make collective operations with a neutral element (e.g. `0` if `MPI_SUM`). That being said, does it make sense to call subroutines that perform collective operations under the hood but with **not** all the ranks ?

Comment: After realising I'd misunderstood the question I was thinking along the lines of @Gilles. However, there could be an issue with the reduce (not the allreduce) which singles out world rank 0 who might not be participating ...

Answer (score 1):

This is always an issue in MPI - how do you tell all the other ranks when one rank is finished? The easiest approach is for everyone to set a true/false flag and then do an allreduce to see if anyone finished. Using this code at the end seems to work

```
  for(j = 0; j < ITERATIONS; j++)
    {
      /* Function which calls MPI_Allreduce */
      reduce_stddev(world_rank, world_size, num_elements_per_proc);

      int finished = 0;

      /* Simulates some processes leaving the loop early */
      if( (j == (ITERATIONS/2)) && (world_rank % 2 == 0))
      {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d finished\n", world_rank);
        fflush(stdout);
        finished = 1;
      }

      /* Check to see if anyone has finished */

      int anyfinished;

      MPI_Allreduce(&finished, &anyfinished, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_LOR,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      if (anyfinished)
      {
         fprintf(stdout, "%d exiting\n", world_rank);
         break;
      }
   }
```

OK - I just reread your question and maybe I misunderstood it. Do you want everyone else to keep calculating?

Comment: Yes, everyone else should keep calculating. Thanks so far.